# Typescript - typing custom React component and HTML elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have some code where I want to specify the JSX element to eventually instantiate.

```js
import { Card } from "card"

...

let Wrapper;
if (card) {
  Wrapper = Card // my custom component
else {
  Wrapper = "label" // the <label> HTML component
}

return <Wrapper>...</Wrapper>
...
```

Obviously Typescript complains here because it see's that I'm attempting to reassign a `React.ReactNode` to a `string`. How would I go about making Typescript happy here?

Comment: Make your own label wrapper component, e.g. `const Label = ({children}) => <label>{children}</label>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is not able to infer the value but it shouldn't complain. `string` is a valid type for `ReactType` (it's different from a `ReactNode`). You can provide a hint to the compiler to help it understand the type. Here is an example:

```
let Wrapper: React.ReactType = "label";
if (Card) {
  Wrapper = Card;
}
```

Here is an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-reacttype-vrbfh).